# Wildfly 10 stack trace not displayed in browser

Tags: jsf, wildfly-10

We recently upgraded from JBoss EAP 6.1 to Wildfly 10.1.0.Final.  We have multiple JSF applications that run in domain mode.  The applications are working fine, but when an error is encountered, it does not display the stack trace or the error in the browser, it just displays "Please see your server log for the actual error".

I have tried setting the following on the default server container and still displays the same message.

```
<servlet-container name="default" stack-trace-on-error="all">
    <jsp-config/>
    <websockets/>
</servlet-container>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How is this JSF related other then you using it? And WHY do you want it displayed in the browser? I'd keep it server side

Comment: This is for a development server and I wanted to point out the servlet technology we were using if that made a difference.  I've searched google and multiple other outlets for an answer and not able to get errors or the stack trace to display in the browser.

Comment: Still it is **not** jsf related...